# Taking last characters of a column of objects and making it the column on a dataframe - pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following:

df =

```
A   B   D
a1  b1  9052091001A
a2  b2  95993854906
a3  b3  93492480190
a4  b4  93240941993
```

What I want:

df_resp =

```
A   B   D
a1  b1  001A
a2  b2  4906
a3  b3  0190
a4  b4  1993
```

What I tried:

```
for i in (0,len(df['D'])):
    df['D'][i]= df['D'][i][-4:]
```

Error I got:

> KeyError: 4906

Also, it takes a really long time and I think there should be a quicker way with pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`pd.Series.str`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.html) string accessor for vectorized string operations.  These are preferred over using `apply`.

If `D` elements are already strings

```
df.assign(D=df.D.str[-4:])

    A   B     D
0  a1  b1  001A
1  a2  b2  4906
2  a3  b3  0190
3  a4  b4  1993
```

If not

```
df.assign(D=df.D.astype(str).str[-4:])

    A   B     D
0  a1  b1  001A
1  a2  b2  4906
2  a3  b3  0190
3  a4  b4  1993
```

---

You can change in place with

```
df['D'] = df.D.str[-4:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `apply()` method of `pandas.Series`, it will be way faster than iterating with a `for` loop...

This should work (provided the column contains only strings):

```
df_resp = df.copy()
df_resp['D'] = df_resp['D'].apply(lambda x : x[-4:])
```

As for the `KeyError`, it probably comes from your DataFrame's index, since calling `df['D'][i]` is equivalent to `df.loc[i]['D']`, i.e. `i` refers to the index's label, not its position. It would (probably) work if you replaced it with `df.loc[i]['D']`, which refers to the index at position `i`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am sorry, you are right, it isn't only strings. It is object type. It contains multiple types. Maybe changing them to strings?

Comment: Actually, a column containing only strings wills always (in my experience) appear as of `dtype object`. What I meant is that if you have `NaNs`, you should change the lambda function to `lambda x : x[-4:] if pandas.notnull(x) else x` (for example).